# Convert Perl regex to Java

Tags: java, regex, perl

I am converting http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/DSTAAL/Mail-Log-Parse-1.0400/lib/Mail/Log/Parse/Postfix.pm to Java.

I am trying to convert the following line

```
($line_info{previous_host_name}, $line_info{previous_host_ip})
                = $line_info{previous_host} =~ m/([^[]+)\[([^\]]+)\]/;
```

If I enter the line into the regexp converter page at http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html I get

```
Unclosed character class near index 18 ([^[]+)\[([^\]]+)\] ^
```

The original perl script executes fine.

Comment: Ok that's enough, the question is now locked until we can be convinced you're going to stop this.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, you can't have this:

```
[^[]
```

This is because Java's character class set operations use nested character classes, and this looks like a malformed one.

```
Operation       Perl (Experiemental)    Java             Result
------------    --------------------    -------------    --------
Union           (?[ [a-e] | [n-r] ])    [a-e[n-r]]       [a-en-r]
Intersection    (?[ [a-m] & [f-r] ])    [a-m&&[f-r]]     [f-m]
Difference      (?[ [a-r] - [f-m] ])    [a-r&&[^f-m]]    [a-en-r]
```

But that's not what you meant. You want the inverse of the character class with just `[` in it (i.e. a character class matching all characters except `[`). For this, you need to escape the `[`:

```
[^\[]
```

The whole thing in Java string literal:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([^\\[]+)\\[([^\\]]+)\\]");
```

Comment: Even if you put another `]` there, same error happens. This line is somehow misleading.

Comment: @ikegami I think revo is just commenting on how misleading the error message is.

Comment: @ikegami Yes, but reading this *It thinks that there should be another `]`.* implies that putting another `]` doesn't produce an error but it does.

Comment: @ikegami You didn't get the point. `[^[]` produces an error, this `[^[]]` and `[^a[]]` too but not this `[^a[b]]` because Java supports some character class operations. The sentence was misleading, better now but still not perfect.

Comment: @ikegami I didn't say that it is. I'm talking about a sentence. Do not expand it to entire solution.

Comment: @revo, Fixed. I hope Sweeper doesn't mind the edits!